# Java split String at point unless something specific follows

Tags: java, regex

here is my problem: The String I get is "Hello. This is my program.java."
I want to split the String at whitespaces and points, but not at ".java".

Right now I have:

```
String.split("\\s*(\\,|\\.|\\s)\\s*");
```

So it looks like this: 
[Hello, This, is, my, program, java].
How can i make it look like this: 
[Hello, This, is, my, program.java] ?

I do not need to split at other fileextension (I dont care about other extensions like .exe or something like that. Only .java matters

Comment: How about removing the file extension first, then splitting by whitespace and punctuation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the negative lookahead: `"(?!\\.java\\b)\\s*(\\,|\\.|\\s)\\s*"`

This says, "split at any number of spaces, followed by a comma or period or a space, followed by any number of spaces... except where it matches `.java` followed by a word end."

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it as simple as

inputString.replaceAll("\.java", "")

Then you can freely split by " " or ".".

Comment: This does not solve for the desired output: `[Hello, This, is, my, program.java]`, except trivially, by re-adding the extension to the last element. And if the filename appears somewhere else (`"my program.java doesn't run"`), which I don't know if OP needs or not, you can't reconstruct it that way, since the position information is lost.